# a dot net framework windows forms app not exiting using `Close();` or other functions

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-framework-version

So i want to close the app without the `X` button but it doesn't work
i tried

```cs
Close();
```

```cs
Enviroment.Exit(0);
```

```cs
Application.Exit();
```

```cs
Application.ExitThread();
```

but none of them work.

Comment: It seems incredibly unlikely that environment.exit wouldn't cause the app to quit. Can you explain in more detail what you see?

Comment: There is more to story... My money is on the code is not actually being run

Comment: maybe it isn't, idk ill try to put it in the load function.

Comment: or use a breakpoint?

Comment: yep it isn't running now and it worked lol.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't running.
and it was in the wrong function.